Weird behaviour with std::vector in c++
Why does this not work?
It's a basic inventory system. inventory is std::vector<Item> and Item is a struct with int quantity and std::string name.
struct Item
{
    int quantity;
    std::string name;
};

void AddItemToInventory(std::string itemName)
{
    Item i;
    i.name = itemName;
    if(inventory.empty())
    {
        i.quantity = 1;
        inventory.push_back(i);
        std::cout << "EMPTY\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto& item : inventory)
        {
            if(i.name == item.name)
            {
                i.quantity = item.quantity + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                i.quantity = 1;
            }
            inventory.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

I was expecting it to work. When it's empty, add one to inventory of name, and when it's not empty just add another. If there exists one, just add 1 to quantity.

Modifying a container while iterating over it with a ranged-for loop results in UB. Anyway, it seems you want std::map rather than std::vector (but debugging the issue with vector probably has learning value).

You are inserting the new item at each iteration of the loop

You don't need the first empty() check, the loop will handle an empty vector just fine.
Your loop is wrong because it is pushing a new Item into the vector on every iteration (which is Undefined Behavior for a range-for loop).
Don't call push_back() inside the loop at all. First loop through the vector looking for the desired Item.  If it is found, you can update it and stop looping. If it is not found, add it after the loop has finished.
Try this:
void AddItemToInventory(std::string itemName)
{
    for (auto& item : inventory)
    {
        if (item.name == itemName)
        {
            item.quantity += 1;
            std::cout << "UPDATED\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    Item newItem;
    newItem.name = itemName;
    newItem.quantity = 1;

    inventory.push_back(newItem);

    std::cout << "ADDED\n";
}

UPDATE: That being said, consider removing the manual loop altogether and use std::find_if() instead, eg:
void AddItemToInventory(std::string itemName)
{
    auto found = std::find_if(
        inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), 
        [&](const Item &item){ return item.name == itemName; }
    );

    if (found != inventory.end())
    {
        found->quantity += 1;
        std::cout << "UPDATED\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        Item newItem;
        newItem.name = itemName;
        newItem.quantity = 1;

        inventory.push_back(newItem);

        std::cout << "ADDED\n";
    }
}


Perhaps worth quoting documentation for push_back. For instance, cppreference.com's page on push_back says: If after the operation the new size() is greater than old capacity() a reallocation takes place, in which case all iterators (including the end() iterator) and all references to the elements are invalidated. Otherwise only the end() iterator is invalidated.

@wohlstad A ranged based for loop isn't the same as a raw for loop IMHO.  For simple things like this I prefer to use them as they are easier to read

The problem is that you cannot add an element to the container (like you do with push_back) during a ranged based iteration over it. You should actually add it after the loop (and only if the element was not found).
However - in this case you can avoid the loop altogether and use std::find_if from the <algorithm> header.
It will search the container and return an iterator to the item (if found), or an end iterator (if not).
A lambda is used to check if the item name matches the name of the item in the container.
This is demonstrated below:
#include <algorithm>   // required for std::find_if

void AddItemToInventory(std::string const & itemName)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(inventory.begin(), 
                           inventory.end(), 
                           [&itemName](Item const& item) { return item.name == itemName; });
    if (it == inventory.end())
    {
        Item i;
        i.name = itemName;
        i.quantity = 1;
        inventory.push_back(i);
        std::cout << "Added\n";
    }
    else
    {
        it->quantity += 1;
        std::cout << "Updated\n";
    }
}

Note that I changed itemName to be a const& to avoid an uneeded copy when passing it to AddItemToInventory.
Demo - Godbolt.
